# Why does this happen in the end of Suspiria?

Tags: plot-explanation, suspiria-2018

In the 2018 movie Suspiria, we see that Mother Suspiriorum kills everyone in the school at the end. Aren't the witches in the school worshiping the three mothers? 
If that where the case, what is Mother Suspiriorum enraged about? Why does she kill her own worshipers?

Comment: I've seen Suspiria few months ago so I don't know if I misunderstood but, if you are referring to the final scene when everything turns red, the mother killed everyone who had worshiped Mergo instead of Mother Suspiriorum. Though I don't know if you are mentioning this scene or another one.

Comment: Yes that's the scene. Marko and all the witches worship the three Mothers. Suspiriorum kills Marko and her followers, I'm not sure why they are killed nevertheless.

Answer (score 1):

She killed them because they were loyal to Marko only (I wrote Mergo because of Bloodborne ahah). Hence, during the film there is a scene where there is a sort of vote, and the majority vote for Marko, making Mother Suspiriorum lose. In brief, Suspiriorum killed those who were not loyal to her, but to Marko.

Comment: I thought it was a vote between Madame Blanc and Marko and Blanc lost. Suspiriorum is one of the three mothers that every witch in the school worshiped.

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Marko won the vote, but she was selfish and detained all the power for herself, pretending to be Mother Suspiriorum, this is the reason why at the end, those who were loyal to Marko were killed, while those who were faithful to Blanc were spared.

Comment: didn't realize she was pretending to be Mother Susperiorum. Is there a conversation or scene in the movie that suggests this? Can you please point me to it?

Comment: At the end, right before Susie evoke the Death, can't remember the exact words that she uses but I'm quite sure that's the scene.

Comment: I watched that scene again. Markos only says death to any other mother. But doesn't claim to be Suspiriorum as such.